# How to take backup locally of my Android App in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I m new to Android Dev.
I have built an app(yet not released on play store) and thinking to add new features to it. But i m not confident enough and I think I might make mistakes and my app might get worse. How to I create a local backup of my android app? Should I just copy the files in which I set my projects to another location or there is another method?

Comment: You do not want to take a backup, you definitely want to use a revision control system like `git`. It offers you the full history of all changes _plus_ backups. You could use a local copy for backups or, much easier and mightier, a service like `github` or `gitlabs`. Do not be afraid of learning how to use such a tool. Yes, it is not trivial, but that is the only sane way for such a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an `Export to Zip File` option in the `File` menu in Android Studio, or you could just make a copy of your project folder - but I'd **strongly** recommend learning to use version control.

A bunch of different version control systems are integrated into Android Studio, Git is the most common one people use and once you know the basics, it's as simple as creating a snapshot of the current state of your project and building a history through those. You can go back to an older version at any time, or compare changes, whatever you like! You can do much more complex things, but it can be as easy as doing `Ctrl+K` every time you finish something important

(You should be backing up your projects anyway - you don't want to lose everything if you get a hard drive failure or something, right? Zip up that project directory regularly and store it somewhere - if you're using Git, you can zip the `.git` folder, that's your repository that contains all the versions of your project)